# Angular 1.5 - Join multiple calls to server from Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've a Directive that, when shown, will make a call to a Service which will return a promise making internally a http call to a server.

That Directive is used in each row so, if I have 200 rows, the Directive will be called 200 times which will call the Service 200 times which will call the server 200 times.

Is there a way to join all calls made to the Service so the Service makes only one call to the server, or several in batchs, and then return the specific data to each Directive via the promise?.

Plnkr example: https://plnkr.co/edit/Sz5W27mirXKER49ORZvo?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])
.service('Service', function($http, $q) {
    this.getStatus = function(id) {
          var status = $q.defer();
          // Obviously, this call is never really made on plnkr.com but it shows the issue
          $http({
              url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
              method: 'GET',
              params: {
                id: id
              }
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {
              status.resolve(response.data.args.id);
          }.bind(this), function errorCallback() {
              status.reject();
          }.bind(this));
        return status.promise;
    };
})
.directive('directive', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<span>{{ status }}</span>',
        scope: {
            id: "=",
        },
        controller: function($scope, Service) {
            $scope.status = '';
            Service.getStatus($scope.id).then(function (status) {
                $scope.status = "status" + status;
            });
        }
    }
})
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    $scope.users.push({id : i, name : 'name' + i});
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide simple and complete sample executable in order to be able to help you.

Comment: A way it should be done depends on how it's done in your case, including API requests and responses. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with your current attempt.

Comment: Sounds like you need to move up to parent array that is used to generate all these rows and make one request from there. As others have mentioned without more specific details hard for anyone to help

Comment: I've added an example on plnkr. My issue is that, due isolation, I'd like  the Directive to be the one responsible of calling the Service and not having to inject the Service to each Controller that uses this Directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alex pointed in the right direction, use Async library. What I need to use is the **cargo** control flow.

Now directives can send a request each one to the Service which will group them on a single http request and send back the response to each directive. Each directive will receive the result of its request but now, instead of making 200 requests, only 1 will be made.

```
.service('Service', function($http, $q) {
    this.cargo = async.cargo(function(tasks, callback) {
        var ids = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            ids.push(tasks[i].id);
        }
        $http({
            url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                ids: ids
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
                tasks[i].q.resolve(response.data.args.ids[i]);
            }
        }.bind(this), function errorCallback() {
            for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
                tasks[i].q.reject();
            }
        }.bind(this));
    });

    this.getStatus = function(id) {
        var q = $q.defer();
        this.cargo.push({q: q, id: id})
        return q.promise;
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One method I have found useful is to have the service save the promise returned by the asynchronous call and return that promise for subsequent calls, if it exists. Once the asynchronous call to the server completes, clear the saved promise so any subsequent requests to the service will call the server again.

https://plnkr.co/edit/TXUBV10xOsRl9nscRmRl?p=preview

```
.service('myService', ['$http', function($http){

  var serverCall = null;
  var callCount = 0;

  return {
    callAsync: callAsync
  };

  function callAsync(){
    if(serverCall == null){
      serverCall = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'https://httpbin.org/delay/3? callCount=' + ++callCount})
      .then(function(response){
        serverCall = null;
        return response.data.args;
     });
    }

    return serverCall;
  }
}])
```

Comment: Ok, I missed to say that every call is different. Imagine that you need to know the status of a user, connected or disconnected. Once you have the list of users each directive gets the user id of its row and calls to retrieve it's status.